# Apply a space character before a table in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two rows and one column which is surrounded by P tag.

After P I have inserted some " " for applying some space to the table from the *start* of the line, but these spaces don't get applied to the table and the table was shown from the start of the line.

```css
table {float: left; background: green;}
```

```html
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family:b titr">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <textarea id='MainSign' name='MainSign' style='background-color:transparent; width:   150px; height: 150px; border: none'></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br />شیطون<br />مدیریت کل
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

Comment: have you tried using margin?

Comment: No i can't using margin since this space applied with end user and I must show table with this spaces, Before showing table I don't know about space or margin

Comment: are you looking for this one? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvL8yfL/)

Comment: Yes, with margin left or right It is true, but as i say before I can't use margin since this spaces will applied in ckeditor

Answer (score 2):

The <table> tag creates a newline when it is used. So *all* your spaces are created above the table. The best way to make it possible is use inline CSS code:

```
<table style="margin-left: 2cm;">
```

There isn't any need of making the table within a <p> tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know margin length before i insert table into p tag

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to move your table away from the left border. You can do this easily with CSS, without adding `&nbsp;`.

Check this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbbh72ya/).

I changed the background color to red for easy to understand. Then I gave a id for the table. As `id='MainSign'` with CSS and then I changed the `margin-left`:

```
#mainTable{
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

You can use any value instead of "100px;".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, with margin left or right It is true, but as i say before I can't use margin since this spaces will applied in ckeditor, I only insert table into p tags and others tags will applied with ckeditor base on end user actions

Comment: found a bit unorthodox answer. Check Fiddle [Fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/5Lyrev4e/) What I did was remove the Table tag and make the whole content to position absolute.

Comment: I only apply style or change, Remove, extend the table tags and i don't know about other tags, other tags are generated automatically with CkEditor based on end user action in the edit her text

Answer (score 0):

`Table` can't be inside a `paragraph` (`paragraph` is closed when `table` begins).

Use `float` to indent table by spaces in a paragraph. And you can remove `span` and `strong` too; they are empty and closed when `table` begins.

```
p {float: left; background: red; margin: 0;}
table {float: left; background: green;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5439pj0p/

#### Note:

HTML, which is rendered by the browser from your code, is:

```
<p>
    <strong>
        <span></span>
    </strong>
</p>

<table>...</table>
<strong></strong>
<p></p>
```

Here is a fiddle where you can see that there are really two `strong` elements (yellow, size of 10x10 pixels).

http://jsfiddle.net/5439pj0p/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes if I apply float:left or float:right for both <table> and <p> tag It is true, But i can only Apply float for table since  p tag Applied with ckeditor and in this sample this table have inserted into p but I don't know that my table tag inserted into wich html tag

Comment: @MasoudBahrami: if table isn't inserted, `table {float: left;}` do nothing, but can be in CSS. You can fire the CKEditor output by parent ID, eg. `#content table {float: left;}` to avoid styling all tables in document.

Comment: But i don't know parent ID of the table, you know i have three element one image and two string that must be shown above  each other i.e first show image then show first string bellow image and second above first string, also the count of the string may be more than two depend on where I want inserted them, this elements are inserted by Me in the output of the CkEditor, I used <br /> for inserted strings above each other, but It may be user applied some space, and this spaces applied only on first row, so I decided insert this element into table

Comment: @MasoudBahrami: you know parent element ID (somewhere in your script you generate an output from CKEditor), eg. `<div id="content">here goes CKEditoroutput</div>`, etc. If you still think you don't know parent el., your task is simply unreal.

Comment: @MasoudBahrami: with info you put in your Q and comments above I can't help you more than I answered. But in my answer is all you need to achieve solution of your task.